# Get the progress of Task.Delay()? Get the progress of long-time running procedure?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

In a procedure, I have

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var timeout = rnd.Next(3000,10000);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(timeout);

await Task.Delay(timeout);
```

I want to know the completed percentage of "Task.Delay(timeout)". Or is there a function that I can get the completed percentage of the whole procedure?

In general, how can I get a progress of a longtime running task? Is there a specific function help doing that?

Thank you!

Comment: One way I thought is set a timer when the delay starts. Then I can get a response from timer every second. Then percentage = timeCountedByTimer / timeout *100.         Is this okay??

Comment: You should separate a big tasks to multiple smaller tasks and then run sub tasks one by one. Progress can then be easily calculated out. A big task like delaying a long time gives you no opportunity to report progress.

Answer (score 2):

The standard way of reporting progress is via `IProgress`. Since `Task.Delay` doesn't take an `IProgress`, you'll have to do it yourself by splitting the large delay into multiple small delays.